# React useEffect hook and returning data

Tags: reactjs

I'm still learning React and it's hooks and I keep running into an issue that I have not been able to figure out.

In a nutshell, I am using the useEffect and useState to basically pull data from a postgres database, with express working as the middleware.  The routes work and everything is active and running, however, it keeps returning blank data.  I am trying set it to spit out each item in the list.  I first thought maybe it has to do with how I passed the prop but everything I've seen is showing me that it's being passed correctly.  I'm out of ideas so I'm giving this a shot.

Here's the parent code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Catalogitems from './Catalogitems.jsx'


function Catalog() {
  const [books, setbooks] = useState([])
  const url = "http://localhost:3001/api/books/"

  const getData = () =>
    fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())

    useEffect(() => {
      getData().then((data) => setbooks(data))
    },[])
 


  return (
    <div>
    
      {books.map(item => <Catalogitems props={item} />)}

    </div>
  )
}

export default Catalog
```

And here's the child:

```
import React from 'react'
function Catalogitems({title, author, ISBN, genre_id,front_cover_image}) {
  return (
    <div className="catalogItem">
      <img  className="bookpicture" src={front_cover_image} alt="Broken picture link" />
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p> Author:{author}</p>
      <p>ISBN: {ISBN}</p>
      <p>Genre: {genre_id}</p>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Catalogitems
```

Here's an example response from the server:

```
 {
    "books_id": 1,
    "title": "Monster Hunter",
    "author": "R.L. Stine",
    "ISBN": "123456",
    "front_cover_image": 1,
    "genre_id": 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a prop *called* "props" here:

```
{books.map(item => <Catalogitems props={item} />)}
```

However, your child component isn't expecting a "props" prop; if it did it would look like this:

```
function Catalogitems({props}) {
  const {title, author, ISBN, genre_id,front_cover_image} = props;
  // ...
```

You *could* destructure it in the arguments, like so:

```
function Catalogitems({props: {title, author, ISBN, genre_id,front_cover_image}}) {
```

But (as @Pauline noted) an easier fix would be to "spread out" your `item` into multiple props, like so:

```
{books.map(item => <Catalogitems {...item} />)}
```

Doing this would allow you to keep your original Catalogitems signature of:

```
function Catalogitems({title, author, ISBN, genre_id,front_cover_image}) {
```

P.S. As a side note, it's conventional to name your variables with new words capitalized, eg. `CatalogItems` or `setBooks`.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried both methods and had success with both, though I also admit I read and did Pauline's answer incorrectly.  After I realized that mistake I went and tried it correctly and it worked.  Which, honestly confused me.  Why does that work? I didn't specify [...item] as a prop to be passed via using props=.
Thanks again for your help.  Its  working now.

Comment: You have to remember that all JSX ultimately gets turned into Javascript, and in Javascript `props` are just another object, made up of the JSX attributes.  When you use the spread operator in this way, it "spreads" the object's properties out into being individual properties on the `props` object ... ie. into being individual `props`.

Comment: P.S. Please don't forget to accept the best answer, and upvote any helpful answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use spread to pass the whole array/object <Catalogitems {...item} />